# Angular 2 - how to clean array in form

Tags: arrays, forms, angular, angular2-forms

I need help.
I create app in Angular2(4) where I have Form with 2 select boxes and 1 checkbox. And I want to achieve dependence this boxes. For example I have this array:

```
dataJSON = [
    {
      productName: 'Product 1',
      variants: [
        {
          variantName: 'Variant1',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'
          ]
        },
        {
          variantName: 'Variant2',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'
          ]
        },
        {
          variantName: 'Variant3',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      productName: 'Product 2',
      variants: [
        {
          variantName: 'Variant1',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4'
          ]
        },
        {
          variantName: 'Variant2',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      productName: 'Product 3',
      variants: [
        {
          variantName: 'Variant1',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'
          ]
        },
        {
          variantName: 'Variant2',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'
          ]
        },
        {
          variantName: 'Variant3',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'
          ]
        },
        {
          variantName: 'Variant4',
          variantType: [
            'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

So when I in first select box choose 'Product 1' then in second select box I will have options: 'Variant1', 'Variant2', 'Variant3'. Then when I choose 'Variant1' I will have in checkboxes options: 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'.
When I choose everithing I want save what and base on that make request to API for data.

What I have now.

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <label>Product</label>
        <select formControlName="productName" (change)="productChanged()" class="form-control">
          <option >Pick a Product...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let l of dataJSON">{{l.productName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        <label>Variant</label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <select formControlName="variants" (change)="variantsChanged()" class="form-control">
          <ng-template  ngFor let-variant [ngForOf]="(variantAfterChangeEvent)">
          <option>Pick a variant...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let v of variant.variants">{{v.variantName}}</option>
          </ng-template>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <label>Type</label>
        <ng-template  ngFor let-type [ngForOf]="(typeAfterChangeEvent)">
          <div *ngFor="let t of type[0].variantType">
            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" (change)="onChange(t, $event.target.checked)"> {{t}} 
          </div>
        </ng-template>            
      </div>
    </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>

variantAfterChangeEvent: any[];
typeAfterChangeEvent: any[];
productForm: any;


constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.productForm = fb.group({
        productName: [],
        variants: [],
        type: this.fb.array([])
    });
}

productChanged() {
    const productName = this.productForm.get('productName').value;
    this.variantAfterChangeEvent = this.dataJSON.filter(s = > s.productName);
}

variantsChanged() {
    const variants = this.productForm.get('variants').value;

    this.typeAfterChangeEvent = this.variantAfterChangeEvent
      .filter((element) =>
        element.variants.some((subElement) => subElement.variantName === variants))
      .map(element => {
        const newElt = Object.assign({}, element ); // copies element
        return newElt.variants.filter(subElement => subElement.variantName === variants);
    });
}

onChange(type: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const typeFromArray = <FormArray>this.productForm.controls.type;

    if (isChecked) {
      typeFromArray.push(new FormControl(type));
    } else {
      const index = typeFromArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === type)
      typeFromArray.removeAt(index);
    }

    console.log('onChange() ' + JSON.stringify(this.productForm.value));
 }

 submitForm() {
    console.log('submitForm ' + JSON.stringify(this.productForm.value));
 }
```

But now when I choose Product -> Variant -> Type and than before Submit I want change Product and choose something else different Product -> Variant -> Type and then Submit I get what I choose as last but in 'type' I have also what I choose first time. So how can I clean 'type' array in productForm when I change somenting in Form = Product or Variant.
And also how can I disable Submit Form Button when not all items(boxes) are selected?

EDIT:
[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/a1749LowTYOz5sqKPDJC?p=preview)

Comment: could you create a plunker with your structure?

Comment: It would be better if you could create a plunker. Based on what  I understood, you can get ngModel from each control and clear other control's value on change. To disable the form until all values are selected, add `required` property in each control and add `[disabled]="!productForm.valid"` in submit button.

Comment: I add plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/a1749LowTYOz5sqKPDJC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could create a plunker.
 Based on what I understood, you can get `ngModel` from each control and clear other control's value on change.

To disable the form until all values are selected, add `required` property in each control and add `[disabled]="!productForm.valid"` in submit button

Comment: I add plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/a1749LowTYOz5sqKPDJC?p=preview